# Do organic veggies contain more pesticides than regular food?

Tags: food, agriculture

Since organic farms can only use "natural" organic approved pesticides rather than frequently more effective "synthetic" pesticides in use by other farms, does it mean that, on average per kg of veggies harvested, a higher amount of pesticide is applied at organic farms in comparison to regular farms? And does it imply that organic veggies sold in stores have more pesticide inside them than regular veggies?